# How to use for loop to sum items

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate the total price of items after adding them to a combo box from a list box. In the list box I have both the type of item and ts price. I want to see the total price to increase as I add each item (click addButton) to the combo box. But what i am seeing is that the item is added to the combo box but I see only individual item prices instead of the sum of the prices. Here is a sample of my code.

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal price;     // variables to holds the price

    decimal total = 0; // variables to hold the total
    int counter;

    for (counter=0; counter <= 5; counter++)
    {      
        price = decimal.Parse(priceLabel2.Text);
        // add items price 
        total += price;

        // display the total amount 
        costLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: If you add 4 items, is the total being shown (currently) just the last one added?

Comment: yes it shows only the last one.

Comment: It would be far easier to help if you post code that is relevant to the description you give. You explain about a list box and a combo box, and then post code that deals with some labels. Also, please fix the indentation.

Comment: in each click you init your total back to 0 and add only the last one

Comment: try to learn more about - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
         decimal price;     // variables to holds the price

        decimal total = 0; // variables to hold the total
        int counter;

          for (counter=0; counter <= 5; counter++)
           {

           price = decimal.Parse(priceLabel2.Text);
            // add items price 
            total += price;

            // display the total amount 
             costLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");
          }
```

to:

```
    decimal total = 0; // variables to hold the total

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal price; // variables to holds the price

        int counter;

        for (counter = 0; counter <= 5; counter++)
        {
            price = decimal.Parse(priceLabel2.Text);
            // add items price 
            total += price;

            // display the total amount 
            costLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }
    }
```

The important change here is moving the total variable *outside* the function. This means that the value is maintained between clicks. If you put it inside the function it is reset to 0 on every click (which is not what you wanted).

Comment: I didn't vote on your question, but you could have done the following : (1) fix the indentation, (2) explain why moving the variable `total` outside the function solves the problem. I believe that's what got you downvotes. Also there's another way : get the current total value from the `costLabel` at the beginning of the function so you don't have an external variable.

Comment: Great feedback - thanks @Rafalon and FCin . I have made some changes based on your comments. Thanks again!